# php - прерываение по таймеру

Tags: php, таймер, break

В php (консольное приложение) нужно прерывать выполнение кода регулярно, скажем 1 раз в секунду и вызывать свою функцию, что-бы выводить статус.
Т.е. что-бы именно основной поток прерывался и заходил в мою функцию, а не другой поток.
Можно ли указать участок коды выполнение которого нельзя прерывать ? Т.е. что-бы при заполнении струкруры данных, она либо полностью была заполнена либо ещё не тронута.
Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: PHP - скриптовый язык программирования. 
Соответственно, он либо отрабатывает до конца, либо его исполнение обрывается из-за ошибок или остановки, прописанной в коде. 
Он не умеет "ждать", увы.

Comment: Как вариант. Основной скрипт скажем пишет в файл (файлы). Второй скрипт раз в секунду пытается его читать, если в файле есть что-то, что считается законченным - второй скрипт производит с этим действие.

Comment: Это не то. В линуксе можно реализовать прерывание через сигналы. В Виндоусе похоже никак ?